# How to access an entry in a list of lists and print the other entries in that list

Tags: python, list

For simplicity sake let's say I'm using a list as follows:

```
[['Bob', 'Pizza', 'Male'], ['Sally', 'Tacos', 'Female']]
```

I want to ask the user which person's stats they would like to view such that it would print out `Bob`, `Pizza`, and `Male` when it was called. I tried to use the index method but the list of lists I'm working with has well over 150 entries.

I tried to use something like:

```
personName = input("Enter the person whose stats you would like to see: )
personIndex = personList.index(personName)
personStats = personList[personName][1:3]  # first index is the name, index 1 and 2 is favorite food and gender
print(personStats)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use a dict() where names are the keys

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use index, you can do it like below:

```
lst=[['Bob', 'Pizza', 'Male'], ['Sally', 'Tacos', 'Female']]
personName = input("Enter the person whose stats you would like to see:" )
ind = [i[0] for i in lst].index(personName)
food, gender = lst[ind][1:]
Print "{0} is a {1} , a {2} lover".format(personName, gender, food)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahsanul's way is not very efficient because it gets the first item of each list even if the first one matches.  Mine is short-circuiting:

```
index = next(i for i, v in enumerate(personList) if v[0] == personName)
```

If there is a possibility that it doesn't exist, you can have a default like this:

```
index = next((i for i, v in enumerate(personList) if v[0] == personName)), my_default)
```

If you want the index only to get the value, change the first `i` to a `v` to get the value in the first place so that you don't need to worry about the extra processing time of finding the value at that index.